# How is functions.php loaded in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy

I am starting to study Wordpress a bit deeper and i d like to know which way functions.php file is loaded so that every function is available everywhere in the theme files.
Or at least if you suggest me some source where to find this information.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ### A `function.php` file:
>
> - Executes only when in the currently activated theme's directory.
> - Applies only to that theme. If the Theme is changed, the functionality is unused.
> - Requires no unique Header text.
> - Is stored with each Theme in the Theme's subdirectory in wp-content/themes.
>
> Each theme has its own functions file, but only the functions.php in the active Theme affects how your site publicly displays. If your theme already has a functions file, you can add code to it. If not, you can create a plain-text file named functions.php to add to your theme's directory.

- Source @ **https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained**.

In short, the `function.php` file is a function wrapper. Each function is hooked to a specific action hook. These actions are called when a user opens a page (Server request).

You can get a better understanding of how action hook work by looking at the [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) which represent a typical hook firing sequence.